# access to symbol table - Segmentation fault

Tags: c, debugging, elf, symbol-table

I am writing a debugger and I need access to the `symtab` but while running I get a Segmentation fault   (core dumped) the problem might be in the way I'm getting the `symatb` (and the header....)
this is the code :

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        FILE* file= fopen(argv[1],"r");
        Elf64_Ehdr* header = (Elf64_Ehdr*)file;
        Elf64_Shdr *section = (Elf64_Shdr*)(file+header->e_shoff);
    
    for(int i=0; i < header->e_shnum; i++) {
        if(section[i].sh_type==SHT_SYMTAB)
        {
            Elf64_Sym *symtab = (Elf64_Sym *)(file+section[i].sh_offset);
....
```

Comment: Maybe you should use a debugger on your debugger to see why it's crashing... :D

Comment: I tried to debug but I dont have enough info to understand why it's crashing , I am trying to figure out if this the right way to get the symtab and I can continue from here

Answer (score 2):

`FILE* file= fopen(argv[1],"r")` does not cause the contents of the file to be read into memory. The returned pointer `file` does not point at anything resembling the file's data. It points to an abstract data structure which can be passed to system library functions like `fread()`, which do read data from the file.

So casting `file` to `Elf64_Ehdr*` is not meaningful. If you want to map the file into memory, which is probably the simplest solution to your problem, you can use `mmap`. (But note that `mmap` requires a file descriptor returned by `open()`; it is not part of the standard C library, and it doesn't know anything about `FILE` objects.)

Comment: unfortunately I am  not allowed to use mmap or readelf or any other helpful libraries

Comment: is there any other way that I can get an access to the symtab? ( in order to search for a specific symbol )

Comment: @dana: read the data yourself into your own buffers.

Comment: 'FILE* file= fopen(argv[1],"r");
 Elf64_Ehdr *header ;
 fread(header, sizeof(header), 1, file);
 Elf64_Shdr *section = (Elf64_Shdr*)(header+header->e_shoff);'

Comment: @dana You should try to _understand_ the code you are writing. `Elf64_Shdr *section ...` part is clearly bogus.